# java actionlistener problem

Tags: java, if-statement, event-listener

Im trying to make a symple login system using swingf, I am having some trouble with if statements to check the login details if you can find any falts in my code that would be great :)(the second if statement does not fire if test is entered in the text box )

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
  if ((e.getSource()) == loginButton)
  {
    login();
  }
}

 public void login()
 {
     String test = loginField.getText();
     System.out.println(test);
     if (test == "test")
     {
             System.out.println(test);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to compare the String test to "test".

In Java, you compare two strings like this:

```
if (test.equals("test")) {
```

the == operator will only return true if both strings are the EXACT same object.